# 2 Questions about clone method

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, c++98

I have two questions here.

1. Is it necessary to add the `virtual` keyword in the derived class?
2. Is there any difference between returning a pointer of the `Derived` class or the `Base` class in the `Derived::clone()` method?

```cpp
class Base
{
    virtual Base* clone() const = 0;
};
    
class Derived : public Base
{
    virtual Derived* clone() const;
};
```

Comment: *"I have two questions here"*. One question by question is better. You might even have better title then.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's not necessary, but highly recommended [1] to add either `virtual` to the beginning or - preferred - `override` [2] to the end.
2. The difference is, when you're already aware that you have a `Derived` class that you're cloning, you don't need to cast:

```
Derived d;
Derived* pd = d.clone(); // without covariant return types,
                         // you'd need to cast here
```

[1] A notable exception is when you'd like to parametrize in a template base class whether a given method is `virtual` or not.

[2] Even though c++98 doesn't have `override`, I still recommend to use this:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#define OVERRIDE override
#else
#define OVERRIDE
#endif
```

That way, you might seamlessly go from c++98 to c++11 (or later).

Comment: override  won't work for c++98. You may want to make a note of that in your answer.

Comment: @drescherjm Could you say what is the year now?:)

Comment: The question is tagged for c++98, I didn't add that tag.

Comment: Note: `override` is not simply preferred for stylistic reasons - it conveys more intention to the reader and demands that the compiler confirm this intention.   (Edit - argh, it's 1998 again?)

Comment: @drescherjm Added a note on how I recommend doing this with c++98.

Comment: @DrewDormann Tonight we're gonna party like it's 1998.

Comment: @user4581301 Enjoy your `std::auto_ptr`.

Comment: c'mon, a few years ago I had interview question of C with classes...

Comment: Well if you look at it in geologic time, Antikythera is a hot new computing device...